# Expandable, very specific keyval processing

Tags: macros, conditionals, expansion, key-value

I am having a hard time trying to come up with an fully expandable keyval parsing macro which deals only with specific keys/values. I wouldn't even attempt this in full generality, that's way beyond me. Here is as far as I've got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\foo@bar{value}

\def\thing@i#1{%
  \thing@ii#1&}

\def\thing@ii#1=#2&{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{form}}
    {#2}
    {}}

\catcode`\==11
\csuse{foo@\thing@i{form=original}}

\end{document}
```

Aside from the problem of having to catcode "=" (and then somehow having to catcode it back again later when "=" doesn't mean "=" any more), This doesn't work due to some expansion issue with the `\ifthen` it seems. I am a bit numb looking at this now, I've tried using `\ifx` etc. but no luck. There seems to be no way to get fully expandable keyval processing and so I'm reduced to doing something which hard-codes the possible keys etc. I have to have this because I will have macros with keyval args which need fully expanding to construct csnames.

Comment: The `\ifthenelse` tests are not expandable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\ifthenelse` tests are not expandable. You can use `\pdfstrcmp` for the comparison (and `\pdf@strcmp` is better because it's engine independent):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,pdftexcmds}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\foo@bar{value}

\def\thing@i#1{%
  \thing@ii#1&}

\def\thing@ii#1=#2&{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{form}=\z@
    #2%
  \fi}

\def\foo@original{ORIGINAL} % provide a definition for testing
\csuse{foo@\thing@i{form=original}}

\end{document}
```

You can also strip spaces (but note that this will strip also "internal spaces", so no options with a space in the name):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,pdftexcmds}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\foo@bar{value}

\def\thing@i#1{%
  \thing@ii#1&}

\def\thing@ii#1=#2&{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\zap@space#1 \@empty}{form}=\z@
    \zap@space#2 \@empty
  \fi}

\def\foo@original{ORIGINAL} % provide a definition for testing
\csuse{foo@\thing@i{form=original}}

\csuse{foo@\thing@i{form =original}}

\csuse{foo@\thing@i{form = original}}

\csuse{foo@\thing@i{ form = original }}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks - it is rather annoying that I tried exactly this after fearing that the `\ifthen` stuff wasn't expandable but now realise I had a typo when I tried it. This at least confirms that it's the right way to do it ...

Comment: One question - is there an expandable way you know of of stripping spaces from the beginning/end of strings? The strings to compare with `\pdf@strcmp` may come with leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: @PLK I was expecting this. ;-)

Comment: I'm embarrassingly glad to hear it :-)

Comment: @PLK Solution ready. ;-)

Comment: Superb, many thanks. The only thing I knew was that the magic macro would have "space" in the name ...